# package.json gets corrupted during publication?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Does anyone know why and when a package.json file for an NPM project would get overwritten like it does in the picture? Left is before, right is after.

Answer (score 1):

I see mention of `Travis CI` in some of the mutated properties. Check your Travis installation for some kind of GitHub integration hook that is allowed to append it.

Comment: ah yes that could be it, I found it very strange that NPM would mess up like that...I am using Travis, but I am not sure how the code ends up in my integration or master branch. I would think Travis would check out its own branch (that never gets checked back into real branches), weird.

Comment: actually, unfortunately, I don't think that's it - I have a project that doesn't use Travis, and it has the same problem. I think it's an NPM version 5 problem.

Comment: There are a few mentions of Git related things in there also. Maybe check a) your code editor and see if you have a plugin or something that could be allowed to auto-update like that, and b) investigate everything Git related.

Comment: You could quickly try a different code editor. If it stops you can isolate it to that immediately.

Comment: Could be Webstorm, but consider how bad NPM version 5 has been, it's probably just NPM v5.

Comment: Try VS Code. It's extremely good, so you should really sample it anyway :) I think the React Native, create-react-native-app, recommends NPM 4.6.1 or 4.6.2.

Comment: yeah, I have had the most luck with NPM v4.6.1, there seem to be major problems with NPM v5...I think it's NPM not Webstorm

Comment: Maybe thats why mine keeps locking up when i do random `npm install`s

Comment: It seems to have underwent massive changes related to filesystem locking.

Comment: Yeah my issues is that symlinks in v5 seem to behave very different, and seem completely broken now